# Why am I not able to run a website which ‘requires javascript’

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, javascript

I am using an iPad mini 2. When I open [this website](http://bihar-nts-nmmss.in/) in Google Chrome it says “This site requires JavaScript. Please enable Javascript to view the website.” Although I have enabled javascript, but still this website is not opening. Please help me.

[image: screeshot of website]

Comment: If anyone wants more information, please comment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the web site is simply broken.

When your browser connects to a web site it sends along a so called "user agent"-string, which specifies which browser, browser version and operating system, you're using.

That specific web site uses that information to only show the real page to user agents that it allows. Others will be shown that incorrect page telling you to enable Javascript - which is misleading.

In order to access the web site from an iPad, you'll need to a use a browser that allows you to change your user agent. That is not possible with the standard Safari.

If you're on a Mac, you can enable the Developer menu in Safari system preferences. From the developer menu, you can choose "User Agent => Google Chrome - Windows", and then you get to the real page.

Comment: Do you know such websites for ipad?